# Is there a ready solution in matplotlib to plot times?

Tags: python, time, matplotlib, plot

This question has two parts. If it lacks of search for other sources plz be patient. This is part of my problem.

I wrote a script using data produced by [tespeed](https://github.com/Janhouse/tespeed). The data has the format "YYYYMMDDhhmm,down rate, up rate,unit,server" (hh:mm of ...).

```
201309221537,0.28,0.04,"Mbit","['speedtest server']"
201309221542,5.78,-1.00,"Mbit","['speedtest server']"
201309221543,0.15,0.06,"Mbit","[...]"
```

This script plots the above data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env    
python2.7                                                                                    
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

def main():
    x = []
    y = []
    with open('/path/to/my/public_html/stdout_tespeed_log.csv','r') as csvfile:
        strData = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in strData:
            x += [float(row[0])]
            y += [float(row[1])]
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y,'+', label='Average download')
    plt.gca().xaxis.major.formatter.set_scientific(False)
    plt.gca().xaxis.major.formatter.set_powerlimits((-2,13))
    locs,labels = plt.xticks()
    plt.xticks(locs, map(lambda x: "%12.0f" % x, locs))
    plt.axis([x[0], x[-1],0,6.5])
    plt.xticks(rotation=20)
    plt.xlabel('Date [YYYYMMDDhhmm]')
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    # plt.legend(loc=3)

    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.savefig("/path/to/my/public_html/speed.png")

main()
```

At the end this produces a plot like this:
[image: the plot]

The time axis is not well configured. :-/ The periodically appearing gaps are because of the fact that there are no minutes 60 - 99 in every hour.

Is there some elegant way to accomplish this? Maybe a ready to go module? ;-)

Comment: Parse the dates to `datetime` objects before plotting. `x += [datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')]`

Comment: @ViktorKerkez: Ok, inserted `import datetime` and replaced your suggestion. Got the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'`. datetime should be finde, because `>>> print(dt.date.today())
2013-09-22` behaves how expected.

Comment: use `from datetime import datetime`.  That module has some unfortunate naming choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib accepts `datetime`s, so you can parse the times with

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

and that should work fine.

The formatting options won't work (`.set_scientific(False)`) this way, though, and your

```
plt.xticks(locs, map(lambda x: "%12.0f" % x, locs))
```

should be replaced with something like

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
...
plt.gca().xaxis.major.formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```